# How to get selected bar x-axis value using MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using the [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library in my Android graphs app and I need to display the dialog with a title containing the selected bar's x-axis values.

I referred to this [wiki entry](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Interaction-with-the-Chart) for click events to the bars in the bar graph. But now I need to get the selected bar x-axis value as a title. Can any one tell me how to achieve it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `OnChartValueSelectedListener`:

```
@Override
public void onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h) {

   final String x = chart.getXAxis().getValueFormatter().getFormattedValue(e.getX(), chart.getXAxis());
}
```

The `Highlight` object **contains additional information** regarding the selected position, such as the dataSetIndex, x- and y-position of the selected value in pixels, the selected stack value (in stacked bar chart), ...

Also hava a look at the **[documentation of highlighting values](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Highlighting)**.

Comment: This answer applies to MPAndroidChart version 2.x.x. See the community wiki answer for how to do this in MPAndroidChart 3.x.x.

Comment: how to get Index  in ver 3.0.6 of particular selected part of chart  i have to show other  ?? will you please add any example code for new version because its changes methods and parameters

Comment: if you want to get an index of the x axis  . . . . int index =  (int)e.getX();

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: for MPAndroidChart 3.x.x the following works as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41219407):

```
chart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h) {
        chart.getXAxis().getValueFormatter().getFormattedValue(e.getX(), chart.getXAxis());
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected() {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the onValueSelected:

```
 public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {

   int position =  e.getXIndex();
   Log.d("positin", position );

   //XValue
   final String selectedValue=barchart.getXAxis().getValues().get(position);
   Log.d("selctdX", selectedValue);

   //YValue
   final String selectedYValue = String.valueOf(e.getVal());
   Log.d("selctdY", selectedValue);

}
```

You can get position, xaxis value and yaxis value for selected bar using this code.

Comment: Add some description!

Comment: to get position index  . . . . int index =  (int)e.getX();