# How to get selected bar x-axis name(Strings added to x-axis) using MP Chart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I know this is a duplicate to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34847411/how-to-get-selected-bar-x-axis-name-using-mp-chart-android)`question`

I have followed the same but I am getting the following error :

```
 @Override
    public void onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h) {

    String xAxisValue = mChart.getData().getXVals().get(e.getXIndex());

}
```

> ERROR : cannot resolve getXVals() and cannot resolve getXIndex()

Please help : I have the following x-axis values : India, Australia,US,China

On click of a Bar in barchart I need to get One of the above string

Comment: I have added a community wiki answer for the latest version of the library in the question you linked. Since that question has more upvotes can we close this one as duplicate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get selected bar x-axis value using MPAndroidChart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34847411/how-to-get-selected-bar-x-axis-value-using-mpandroidchart)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [MPAndroidChart 3.0.0+](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) this should work:

```
chart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h) {
        chart.getXAxis().getValueFormatter().getFormattedValue(e.getX(), chart.getXAxis());
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected() {

    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. :)

Comment: Than you so much for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your model class for drawing chart and when you click on bar, wants to get more values instead of just Y axis points or x axis name then below is the solution.

first Your activity or fragment should implements OnChartValueSelectedListener. then implement onValueSelected()

```
@Override
public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {


    String xAxisValue = chart.getData().getXVals().get(e.getXIndex());
    //yourList (model class or  pojo class type), first get the full list
    for (int i=0; i<yourList.size(); i++){
        YourModelClass cym = yourList.get(i);
        String year =cym.getYear();
        // compare the xAxisValue with one of your Model class attribute. which is written on x-axis of the graph
        if (year.equals(xAxisValue)){
            // now you got the index number of your list which is matched with xAxis Bar value. 
            //so do your stuff here. Something like setting text or showing toast etc etc
           // if done everything then break the loop
            break;
        }

    }

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected() {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In Kotlin :- 

barChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(object : OnChartValueSelectedListener {
        override fun onNothingSelected() {
        }

        override fun onValueSelected(e: Entry?, h: Highlight?) {
            val xAxisLabel = e?.x?.let { barChart.xAxis?.valueFormatter?.getAxisLabel(it, barChart.xAxis) }
        }

    })
```