# MPAndroidChart: Listen for click events on xAxis labels

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

How do I get an `onClickListener` for the xAxis labels? If this is not possible, is there any other way to receive click events on the xAxis labels?

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34850792/6799753) it might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The xAxis labels are not actually instances of `View`. Instead, they are rendered directly onto the canvas by MPAndroidChart. So you can't have a `OnClickListener` for them.

The way to do what you want, instead, is to implement a custom [`OnChartGestureListener`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/listener/OnChartGestureListener.java). The javadoc for that class is [here](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.0.1/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/listener/OnChartGestureListener.html)

```
mChart.setOnChartGestureListener(new MyChartGestureListener());
```

In your `MyChartGestureListener` you would override `onChartSingleTapped(MotionEvent me)`:

```
@Override
public void onChartSingleTapped(MotionEvent me) {
    float tappedX = me.getX();
    float tappedY = me.getY();
    MPPointD point = mChart.getTransformer(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT).getValuesByTouchPoint(tappedX, tappedY);
    Log.d(TAG, "tapped at: " + point.x + "," + point.y);
}
```

The snippet above shows how to get the x and y values from the `MotionEvent`. You would then need some logic to check if you are single tapping a label and not another part of the chart. Perhaps a conditional like:

```
if ((point.y) < labelYValue) {
     Log.d(TAG, "tapped on label for x-value: " + point.x);
}
```

Or you could probably use the raw `y` from the `MotionEvent` if you prefer.

Comment: A Transformer was all I needed to know about. I was ignorant enough to ask this question again despite you providing a solution to a similar problem through transformer in one of my previous questions.

Comment: @androidnoob thanks for the accept. It's a reasonable enough question - someone might ask it in the future so I think overall this Q&A helps

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @David, but I compared the click y vs the label y. Hope this help.

```
            override fun onChartSingleTapped(me: MotionEvent?) {
                me?.let { event ->
                    val entry = getEntryByTouchPoint(event.x, event.y)

                    if (event.y > height - xAxis.mLabelHeight) {
                        ToastUtil.showToast(context, "Label click ${entry}")
                    } else {
                       ...
                    }
                }
            }
```